# Why is my header and footer image scale going up 1000% in word only on my machine?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-word, html-editor

So I'm building a letter from a template in html adding in some values from the database and then saving it as a word document. When opening up the file on my machine the header and footer scale is usually something like 800-1000%. When opened on another machine it is 100% always. Same version of word 2016 on each machine.

```
 p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader{
 margin:0in;
 margin-top:.0001pt;
 mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
 tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
 height:0px !important;
 width:0px !important;
}
 p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{
     margin:0in 0in 1in 0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
 }
 <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <div style='mso-element:header' id="h1" >
                 <p class="MsoHeader">
                     <table border="0" width="100%">
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/docs/Images/LetterHead.png" />

                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </p>
            </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <div style='mso-element:footer' id="f1">
             <p class="MsoFooter">
                 <table width="95%" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                         <td align="center" class="footer">
                            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/docs/Images/LetterFoot.png" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </p>
         </div>
     </td>
<td>
    <div style="mso-element:header" id="h2">
    <p class="MsoHeader"><span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span>
    <span style='mso-field-code:" PAGE "'></span> 
    </p>
    </div>
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

EDIT: [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeeU5.png)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you got some faulty Office Settings. There are a number of line realted settings, and any one of those could be messed up for new files. There should be a template for "empty, new Document". That is the thing you would need to edit and save to fix it.

Comment: I found the template but none of the settings seem to relate to default image scale. Did you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: On Stack Overflow it's necessary to prefix the screen name with a `@` in order to notify someone when replying in comments.

Comment: FWIW it's not clear to me what's meant by "Header/Footer scale". Could you include screen shots to show what you're seeing on your machine and what others are seeing, please. And do you see the same behavior in the *body* of the document?

Comment: @CindyMeister I added an image of how it looks and which settings are being changed. Everyone else has 100% and 100% for the scale. The body looks normal.